# Is there way to redirect URL from one domain to new domain using IIS URL rewrite module?

Tags: url, iis, dns, url-rewriting

There are total two domains available in our system. One is "example" and another one is "exe" and we want to redirect all requests from "exe" domain to "example" domain. we want to perform full URL redirection. for example if I am trying to access  “https://exe.test.dir.com/xyz/ref?function=view” then it should only replace domain “exe” to “example” in URL without impacting other query string in URL.

Comment: Then what rules did you try? Edit the question to include those.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this rule

```
<rule name="rule">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="exe.test.dir.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.test.dir.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```